# Safe Thread pause and Resume during Database operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I am creating multiple threads which interact with different databases.Suppose i want to pause that particular thread and resume the same thread without affecting database operation how would i do so.

My code is as shown below

```
 thread begin
 for(;;)
 {
 //do something 
 //Critical section begins
 Database Operation like update or insert usually takes long time
 //Critical section ends
 //do something
 thread.sleep(10000);
 }
```

I have to make sure that whenever i pause the thread it has to wait till the critical section operation is completed.So that resume can be easier.

I am using the below code to pause but throws an exception when database operation is going on.

```
        while (tA1.IsAlive)
        {

            if (tA1.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            {

                tA1.Suspend();
                Status1A.Text = "Upload Paused";

            }
        }
```

How can i safely pause and resume my thread..??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should look into `lock`.

Comment: `Suspend` is deprecated. You shouldn't use that for your safety. It causes deadlocks easily

Comment: @gleng thred suspended when locked will pause the thread after it comes out of lock section...??

Comment: I suspect you're asking the wrong question. What is the larger purpose here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this safely you need to cause the thread to go into the WaitSleepJoin state at a safe point. A safe point is defined as a place in the execution sequence where:

- data structures are guaranteed to be in a consistent state
- *and* the thread is in an obstruction free state

They are both fairly obvious really. The first means that you do not want to pause a thread while it is in the middle of a write to a data structure which could leave it in an inconsistent state. The second means that you do not want to leave a thread in a state where it could cause an obstruction for another thread. In simpler terms this means that you do not want to pause the thread while it is holding a lock for example.

There are a lot of ways to do this, but using a `ManualResetEventSlim` is probably the easiest.

```
public class Example
{
  private ManualResetEventSlim allow = new ManualResetEventSlim();

  public void Start()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkerThread, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); 
  }

  public void Pause()
  {
    allow.Reset();
  }

  public void Resume()
  {
    allow.Set();
  }

  private void WorkerThread()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      allow.Wait(); // Wait at a safe point.
      lock (...)
      {
        // Your database operation goes here.
      }
    }
  }
}
```